# How can i copy a directory in java?

Tags: java, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copying files from one directory to another in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java)
>   [Copy entire directory contents to another directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214703/copy-entire-directory-contents-to-another-directory)

How can i copy a directory in java?

Example  I want dir A to be copied

```
from src\A to dest
```

Final folder structure should be

```
 dest\A.
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Apache Commons IO (v2.1)](http://commons.apache.org/io/). It includes a `FileUtils` which provides that method for you.

> FileUtils.copyDirectory(src,dest)

[FileUtils.html#copyDirectory(java.io.File, java.io.File)](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)

Answer (score 2):

This should help you: [How to copy directory in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-directory-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

`Files.copy(source + "/" + folderName, target + "/" + folderName, REPLACE_EXISTING);`