# Unable to copy "My Documents" in Java

Tags: java, windows, io, nullpointerexception

I am trying to copy files, folders, sub folders, zip files etc from a given location to another location. I used the code below.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class CopyDirectoryExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        File srcFolder = new File("C:\\Users\\Yohan\\Documents");
        File destFolder = new File("D:\\Test");

        //make sure source exists
        if(!srcFolder.exists()){

           System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
           //just exit
           System.exit(0);

        }else{

           try{
            copyFolder(srcFolder,destFolder);
           }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //error, just exit
                System.exit(0);
           }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    public static void copyFolder(File src, File dest)
        throws IOException{

        if(src.isDirectory()){

            //if directory not exists, create it
            if(!dest.exists()){
               dest.mkdir();
               System.out.println("Directory copied from " 
                              + src + "  to " + dest);
            }

            //list all the directory contents
            String files[] = src.list();

            for (String file : files) {
               //construct the src and dest file structure
               File srcFile = new File(src, file);
               File destFile = new File(dest, file);
               //recursive copy
               copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);
            }

        }else{
            //if file, then copy it
            //Use bytes stream to support all file types
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest); 

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int length;
                //copy the file content in bytes 
                while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
                   out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                in.close();
                out.close();
                System.out.println("File copied from " + src + " to " + dest);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I used the above code to take a copy of "My Documents". But unfortunatly, it ended up with `NullPointerException` after running for a while.

The reason for the error is it tried to take a copy of "My Music" folder, which is not even inside of the "My Documents" folder. I tested this code in 2 different machines running windows 7, got the same error in both.

A windows specific solution is fine for me, as I am targeting windows machines at the moment. What have I done wrong?

The error I am getting is below

```
Directory copied from C:\Users\Yohan\Documents\My Music  to D:\Test\My Music
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at CopyDirectoryExample.copyFolder(CopyDirectoryExample.java:51)
        at CopyDirectoryExample.copyFolder(CopyDirectoryExample.java:56)
        at CopyDirectoryExample.main(CopyDirectoryExample.java:25)
```

Comment: Can we see the stack trace? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214703/copy-entire-directory-contents-to-another-directory for a library method that does the copying for you.

Comment: @JPMoresmau: Simply run the code in yours. You will get the same.

Comment: @JPMoresmau: That apache code is not working properly when it meet zip files

Comment: I don't have Windows, but if I saw your error I might be able to give you help.

Comment: @JPMoresmau: Hold on, I will have to run the code again..

Comment: @JPMoresmau: Hi. the error is posted. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this isn't working is because "My Music", "My Pictures" (or Images) and other directories are just symbolic links. See this post on how to detect symbolic links: [Java 1.6 - determine symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813710/java-1-6-determine-symbolic-links)

Comment: Not clear with what I have to really do. Mind providing a code help? Last time I messed up with the`canonical` path

Comment: Tested. It is not working, as the comment in that post has already mentioned.

Comment: @JustCause In `java.nio.file` you have everything out of the box. You can copy a directory and tell it to ignore or follow symlinks. Also you can check `Files.isSymbolicLink(file)`. It would reduce the code a lot. But I don't know if the bug exists there too (hopefully not).

Comment: @JustCause of course you could also catch NullPointerExceptions and assume it wa a symlink, but it's dirty.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, these folders (Images, Music, Videos) are NOT considered symbolic links in Java. Using Java 8,

```
Files.isSymbolicLink(srcFile.toPath())
```

While return false, and `Files.readSymbolicLink(srcFile.toPath())` will fail with an Access Denied Exception.

So you can't process them automatically. Fix your code so that you handle properly the case where `srcFile.isDirectory()` returns true, but `srcFile.listFiles()` return null.

On my Windows 8 machine, three folders were in that case. I'm on a French machine, so I got a "Ma Musique" folder that gave null for `listFiles`. However,

```
new File("C:\\Users\\<user>\\Music").listFiles()
```

Does NOT return null. So I'm afraid you'll have to hardcode special code for the three folders (Music, Videos, Images) if you want to copy the data too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Mind assisting me with some edits to my code? It seems so hard to do these file work in Java, unbelivevable!

Comment: Well they're special folders in windows, clicking on some folder via Windows Explorer gives access denied errors too, so I don't think it's Java's fault. In your code, you have String files[] = src.list(); files can be null, check for that.

Answer (score -1):

You are not handling the empty directories -- try making the following change,
It will work after making the below change.

```
    //list all the directory contents
    String files[] = src.list();

    if (files!=null && files.length>0) {
       for (String file : files) {
          //construct the src and dest file structure
          File srcFile = new File(src, file);
          File destFile = new File(dest, file);
          //recursive copy
          copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);
       }
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly the possibility for your Null Pointer exception. src.list() call returns a null and this happens if your directory does not contains any more sub-elements. I was able to simulate the error condition and after adding a null check the error was removed. Why was this given a negative vote ??