# read directory and create same structure

Tags: java

I want to read a directory and create the same file and sub directories in another directory.

The path for the directory will be a user defined value.

```
private static void readFiles(File sourceFolder, String destePath) {
        if (sourceFolder.isDirectory())
            for (File sourceFile : sourceFolder.listFiles()) {
                if (sourceFile.isFile()) {
                    File destFile = new File(destePath + "/"
                            + sourceFile.getName());
                    updateConnectorXML(sourceFile, destFile);
                } else {
                    {
                        destePath = destePath + "/" + sourceFile.getName();
                        File destFile = new File(destePath);
                        destFile.mkdir();
                        readFiles(sourceFile, destePath);
                    }
                }

            }
    }
```

here e.d sourceFile will be "c:/abc" which is a directory and I am reading files and sub directories of sourceFile. Now in `updateConnectorXML(sourceFile, destFile)` I am just updating XML files.

Now I want to create same directory structure in another folder with updated XML files.

In above code the `destePath` is changed to only one directory and all files are going into the directory. How can I get back from that directory?

Comment: So basically you want to copy files to another directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy entire directory contents to another directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214703/copy-entire-directory-contents-to-another-directory)

Comment: I assume that you want the changes to be applied to your file system right?, even though  your code says otherwise!

Comment: basically in my code, what i am doing is. i am reading directory containing XML files and modifying the files and saving these files in another directory with same directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

One fundamental error is the reuse of parameter destePath for holding the various subdirectory paths. Compare:

```
private static void readFiles(File sourceFolder, String destePath) {
    if (sourceFolder.isDirectory()){
        for (File sourceFile : sourceFolder.listFiles()) {
            if (sourceFile.isFile()) {
                File destFile = new File(destePath + "/"
                        + sourceFile.getName());
                updateConnectorXML(sourceFile, destFile);
            } else {
                String subPath = destePath + "/" + sourceFile.getName();
                File destDir = new File(subPath);
                destDir.mkdir();
                readFiles(sourceFile, subPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```