# Copying directory using Groovy & XMLSulrper data

Tags: java, xml, groovy, xmlslurper

Please help, so I'll avoid tearing my hair out ...

I need to simple Copy folderA to FolderB using a groovy that gets the data from an XML. I have to use XMLSlurper or XMLParser

This is it -

```
println "Start"

def Folders = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("CopyParams.xml"))

Folders.Folder.each
{
it.DirectoryToCopy.each
{
println "Copying ${it.@source} into folder ${it.@target}"

new AntBuilder().copy (
todir: "${it.@target}")
{
fileset(
dir: "${it.@source}" )
}
}
}

println "End"

System.exit(0)
```

Then I get  -

```
> Copying C:\Temp\Groovy\Source_Folders into folder C:\Temp\Groovy\Target_Foler
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: source for class: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject
groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: source for class: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject
at testCopy$_run_closure1_closure2_closure3.doCall(testCopy.gvy:14)
at testCopy$_run_closure1_closure2_closure3.doCall(testCopy.gvy)
at testCopy$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(testCopy.gvy:11)
at testCopy$_run_closure1.doCall(testCopy.gvy:7)
at testCopy.run(testCopy.gvy:5)
```

I tried to use before the Copy -

```
String src = ${it.@source[0]}
String dst = ${it.@target[0]}
```

Or

```
String src = new XmlNodePrinter().print(${it.@source})
String dst = new XmlNodePrinter().print(${it.@target})
```

Then I get -

```
> Copying C:\Temp\Groovy\Source_Folders into folder C:\Temp\Groovy\Target_Foler
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: testCopy.$() is applicable for argument types: (testCopy$_run_
closure1_closure2_closure3) values: [testCopy$_run_closure1_closure2_closure3@1b06cab]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: testCopy.$() is applicable for argument types: (testCopy$_run_closure1
_closure2_closure3) values: [testCopy$_run_closure1_closure2_closure3@1b06cab]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
at testCopy$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(testCopy.gvy:11)
at testCopy$_run_closure1.doCall(testCopy.gvy:7)
at testCopy.run(testCopy.gvy:5)
```

I also tried using FileUtils but got even more none understood errors

What am I doing wrong ?

Will it be better if I'll use "XMLParser" ?

Thanks,
Eli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer with the help of a collegue -

declaring the variables you get from XMLSlurper to be a strings should be with "def"

```
def sourceDir = "${it.@source}"
def destinationDir = "${it.@target}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are of course multiple options/ways to copy the contents of a folder to another folder.

The most simple method is to use `FileUtils.copyDirectory()`, built into Java as described in this SO post: [Copy entire directory contents to another directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214703/copy-entire-directory-contents-to-another-directory)

Alternatively, you can use Java's `Files.copy', described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
...
Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

You could use `AntBuilder`, which you are attempting within your example. You don't need to use `XMLSlurper` at all. `AntBuilder` is capable of copying an entire folder without handling individual files (or can filter out files, i.e. by extension). For example:

```
String sourceDir = SOURCE_DIR_PATH
String destinationDir = DESTINATION_DIR_PATH

new AntBuilder().copy(todir: destinationDir) {
     fileset(dir : sourceDir) {
         exclude(name:"*.java")
     }
```

Or with no filtering, simply:

```
new AntBuilder().copy(todir: destinationDir)
```

Comment: I update my question, I have to use the XMLParser or XMLSlurper, for reading and using other properties, with no connection to the copy.
As for your other suggetions, Tried them, but the object I get from XMLSlurper can't be converted to a FILE so I can't use your suggestions/

Comment: And @pczeus as for you AntBuilder suggetions, You can see the errors I get when using it