# Move all files from folder to other folder with java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copying files from one directory to another in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java)

How can I move all files from one folder to other folder with java?
I'm using this code:

```
import java.io.File;

    public class Vlad {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
            // File (or directory) to be moved
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\i074924\\Desktop\\Test\\vlad.txt");

            // Destination directory
            File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\i074924\\Desktop\\Test2");

            // Move file to new directory
            boolean success = file.renameTo(new File(dir, file.getName()));
            if (!success) {
                System.out.print("not good");
            }
        }
    }
```

but it is working only for one specific file.

thanks!!!

Comment: possible dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java

Comment: This link may help you,
http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/MovingFile.shtml

Comment: The linked question is for *copying* files; the question here is how to *move* files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a `File` object points to a folder you can iterate over it's content

```
File dir1 = new File("C:\\Users\\i074924\\Desktop\\Test");
if(dir1.isDirectory()) {
    File[] content = dir1.listFiles();
    for(int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        //move content[i]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

By using org.apache.commons.io.**FileUtils** class

`moveDirectory(File srcDir, File destDir)`  we can move whole directory

Comment: where do I get this class (I'm new to java)?

Comment: and I want only to move the inner files and not the folder it self.

Comment: Question is to move foilder contents not folder itself.

Answer (score 7):

Since Java 1.7 there is `java.nio.file.Files` which offers operations to work with files and directories. Especially the `move`, `copy` and `walkFileTree` functions might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

- You can rename the directory itself.
- You can iterate over files in directory and rename them one-by-one. If directory can contain subdirectories you have to do this recursively.
- you can use utility like [Apache FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) that already does all this.