# Read files in directory and (if any) copy to folder

Tags: java, file, directory, copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copying files from one directory to another in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java)

I have a folder (c:/InstallationFiles) with .jar files in it. i want to read through it and if the name equals test1 i want to copy it to a test1 folder, then if the name is test2 copy it to a test2 folder etc. this is what i have so far:

private static int copyJARFiles() {

```
    resultCode = 0;

    File installFolder = new File(Constants.WINDOWS + Constants.INSTALLATION_FOLDER);
    File[] installFiles = installFolder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < installFiles.length; i++) {
        if (installFiles[i].equals("test1.jar")){

        }
        if (installFiles[i].equals("test2.jar")){

        }
    }
    return resultCode;
}
```

not sure how to copy it then. im still a rookie.

thank you / kind regards

Comment: wanna to copy jar source folder to destination folder?

Comment: Apologies, .equals will not work. will have to use .toString.contains or similiar.
Yes if the directory contains a file with the name test1 i want to copy/move it to a directory test1(directory already exist)

Comment: DO you want to extract jar or copy jar to destination folder

Comment: just copy the jar to the destination folder, does not have to be a jar file. it can be a .txt file for example. just want to copy it

Answer (score 0):

if you want to copy jar:
You can use **apache IO api**. Use the below code:
FileUtils.copy(sourceFile,destinationFile);

You can also use java 7. It contains direct function to copy files.

if you want extract jar:
You can use java.util.zip.*; package classes.

Please let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < installFiles.length; i++) {
            if (installFiles[i].toString().contains("test1.jar")) {
                Path source = Paths.get("C:/Dir/test1.jar");
                Path target = Paths.get("c:/test1/test1.jar");
                Files.copy(source, target);
}
        return resultCode;

Will something like this work? thank you for the help. much appreciated

Comment: yes, but you have to use Java 7.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < installFiles.length; i++) { if (installFiles[i].toString().contains("test1.jar")) { Path source = Paths.get(**installFiles[i].getPath()**); Path target = Paths.get("c:/test1/test1.jar"); Files.copy(source, target); }  You have mistake in source file path. Please replace as in bold

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, Please like my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood your task but maybe this example will help you

```
for (File f : installFolder.listFiles()) {
    if (f.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
        File targetDir = new File(installFolder, f.getName().replace(".jar", ""));
        if (!targetDir.exists()) {
            targetDir.mkdir();
        }
        File target = new File(targetDir, f.getName());
        Files.copy(f.toPath(), target.toPath());
    }
}
```

The main idea is that Java 7 provides us with Files.copy util