# How to copy file from one location to another location?

Tags: java, io

I want to copy a file from one location to another location in Java. What is the best way to do this?

---

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class TestArrayList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File(
            "D:\\CBSE_Demo\\Demo_original\\fscommand\\contentplayer\\config");
        List<String>temp=new ArrayList<String>();
        temp.add(0, "N33");
        temp.add(1, "N1417");
        temp.add(2, "N331");
        File[] matchingFiles = null;
        for(final String temp1: temp){
            matchingFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return name.startsWith(temp1);
                }
            });
            System.out.println("size>>--"+matchingFiles.length);

        }
    }
}
```

This does not copy the file, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Start with [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) and also try having a look at [Copying a File or Directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html)

Comment: My first problem is how to store that search files ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need, however, take a look at [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/TOC.html), I'd focus somewhere around `List`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying files from one directory to another in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) (or any variant):

```
Files.copy(src, dst, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Also, I'd recommend using `File.separator` or `/` instead of `\\` to make it compliant across multiple OS, question/answer on this available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths).

Since you're not sure how to temporarily store files, take a look at `ArrayList`:

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList();
files.add(foundFile);
```

To move a `List` of files into a single directory:

```
List<File> files = ...;
String path = "C:/destination/";
for(File file : files) {
    Files.copy(file.toPath(),
        (new File(path + file.getName())).toPath(),
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Comment: Files class is available since JDK 1.7..http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: this is only used when you want to copy whole folder from one location to another .But I want to search first and then copy that only search folders.

Comment: In case your `Path` object references a file (say `C:\\mytext.txt`), if copies the file. Ofcourse similar options are available to simply `move` the file (as documented in the given link). As Jai correctly mentioned, make sure you are using JDK 1.7. Otherwise there are other options ofcourse.

Comment: @vijayk If you took the time to read the links I suggested you would have found a number of useful ideas, like [Walking the File Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)...

Comment: +1 for Files.copy but I dont agree about File.separator, File normalizes the path anyway, so back or forward slash makes no difference.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev: You're right. Though in that case OP would be better of using `/` instead of `\\` (as per [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths))

Comment: @Aquillo :I used same arraylist concept but I cant add that search file. In my code I used File[] matchingFiles; Can you please tell me how to add those type of object in ArrayList?

Comment: @vijayk: You are using an `ArrayList` to store `String`s which won't work. You are also using an `array` to store files, though remember this is a fixed size and you cannot **append** to an array, only use available keys (e.g. `myFileArray[0] = new File("");`).

Comment: Though for searching files, I'd recommend taking a look at MadProgrammer's examples. No need to reinvent the wheel, right? :)

Comment: @Aquillo: Suppose I have list of folders which I want to copy . eg.List<File> files = new ArrayList(); files object content all files then how to copy to :D\\ISCE_Demo\\ location?

Comment: @vijayk I've extended my answer.

Comment: @Aquillo: this code only create folders name not copy the content between that folder.

Comment: Try debugging and take a look at the two `Path`s passed to Files.copy().

Comment: This method is working for me properly, But, After some time, the application starts throwing "Too many files open" error when I try to invoke this method.

Answer (score 88):

**Update:**

see also
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67179064/1847899

**Using Stream**

```
private static void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(source);
        os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

**Using Channel**

```
private static void copyFileUsingChannel(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    FileChannel sourceChannel = null;
    FileChannel destChannel = null;
    try {
        sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
        destChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
        destChannel.transferFrom(sourceChannel, 0, sourceChannel.size());
       }finally{
           sourceChannel.close();
           destChannel.close();
       }
}
```

**Using Apache Commons IO lib:**

```
private static void copyFileUsingApacheCommonsIO(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    FileUtils.copyFile(source, dest);
}
```

**Using Java SE 7 Files class:**

```
private static void copyFileUsingJava7Files(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
}
```

**Or try Googles Guava  :**

https://github.com/google/guava

docs:
https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html

Comment: Thanks, Apache Commons FileUtils saved my life, since I needed to build old Java 6 project where nio packages are not available. `FileUtils.copyFile(...)` is even shorter/handy than nio `Files.copy(...)` due to no need of converting the files to Path.

Comment: you can try Googles guava lib also... watch out some Version doesnt support Java 6 .. i will update my post next days

Answer (score 10):

Use the New Java File classes in Java >=7.

Create the below method and import the necessary libs.

```
public static void copyFile( File from, File to ) throws IOException {
    Files.copy( from.toPath(), to.toPath() );
}
```

Use the created method as below within main:

```
File dirFrom = new File(fileFrom);
File dirTo = new File(fileTo);

try {
        copyFile(dirFrom, dirTo);
} catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestJava8.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

NB:- fileFrom is the file that you want to copy to a new file fileTo in a different folder.

Credits - @Scott: [Standard concise way to copy a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java/16600787#16600787)

Answer (score 5):

```
  public static void copyFile(File oldLocation, File newLocation) throws IOException {
        if ( oldLocation.exists( )) {
            BufferedInputStream  reader = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(oldLocation) );
            BufferedOutputStream  writer = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(newLocation, false));
            try {
                byte[]  buff = new byte[8192];
                int numChars;
                while ( (numChars = reader.read(  buff, 0, buff.length ) ) != -1) {
                    writer.write( buff, 0, numChars );
                }
            } catch( IOException ex ) {
                throw new IOException("IOException when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath());
            } finally {
                try {
                    if ( reader != null ){                      
                        writer.close();
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch( IOException ex ){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error closing files when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath() ); 
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Old location does not exist when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath() );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Copy a file from one location to another location means,need to copy the whole content to another location.`Files.copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options) throws IOException` this method expects source location which is original file location and target location which is a new folder location with destination same type file(as original).
Either Target location needs to exist in our system otherwise we need to create a folder location and then in that folder location we need to create a file with the same name as original filename.Then using copy function we can easily copy a file from one location to other.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                String destFolderPath = "D:/TestFile/abc";
                String fileName = "pqr.xlsx";
                String sourceFilePath= "D:/TestFile/xyz.xlsx";
                File f = new File(destFolderPath);
                if(f.mkdir()){
                    System.out.println("Directory created!!!!");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Directory Exists!!!!");
                }
                f= new File(destFolderPath,fileName);
                if(f.createNewFile())   {

                    System.out.println("File Created!!!!");
                }   else {
                    System.out.println("File exists!!!!");
                }

                Files.copy(Paths.get(sourceFilePath), Paths.get(destFolderPath, fileName),REPLACE_EXISTING);
                System.out.println("Copy done!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");


            }
```

Comment: I agree with you on a specific point. Where I see in most of the answers they are using the same directory. I was expecting to see them using a different source(directory) and different destination(directory).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the **Java 8 Streaming API**, **PrintWriter** and the **Files API**

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("destination-path"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    Files.readAllLines(Path.of("src/test/resources/source-file.something"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
         .forEach(pw::println);
}
```

If you want to **modify the content on-the-fly while copying**, check out this link for the **extended example** https://overflowed.dev/blog/copy-file-and-modify-with-java-streams/

Comment: this is a nice and elegant way!

Answer (score 1):

I modified one of the answers to make it a bit more efficient.

```
public void copy(){
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(Files);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream();
        try {
            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                int len = 0;
                try {
                    if (!((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)) break;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void moveFile() {
    copy();
    File dir = getFilesDir();
    File file = new File(dir, "my_filename");
    boolean deleted = file.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Files.exists()

Files.createDirectory()

Files.copy()

Overwriting Existing Files: 
Files.move()

Files.delete()

Files.walkFileTree()
[enter link description here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/files.html#files-copy)

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
FileUtils.copy(sourceFile, destinationFile);
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html