# How to add File [] Array content into ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an array:

```
File [] temp=null;
```

And I have an `arrayList` of `File` type:

```
List <File> tempList = new ArrayList <File>();
```

Now I want to add the content from `temp` to `tempList`. So anyone can please tell me How do I this?

Comment: loop through the `temp` array and add each File to the `tempList`

Comment: Just so others know, adding array contents to an `ArrayList` using a for loop will give you a warning in Android Studio that says it prefers you use the `ArrayList`'s `addAll()` method. You could still do it, but for some reason Android Studio doesn't prefer it (maybe it's more efficient to use the method?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
tempList.addAll(Arrays.asList(temp));
```

Comment: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433915/how-to-copy-file-from-one-location-to-another-location' can you plz see this problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not going to update the content of the array (add/removing element), it can be as simple as

```
List<File> tempList = Arrays.asList(temp);
```

Of course, if you want a list that you can further manipulate, you can still do something like

```
List<File> tempList = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(temp));
```

Comment: The second line of code should be `List<File> tempList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(temp));`, note the diamond in `ArrayList<>`

Comment: Dunno why I missed that lol. Lemme fix that

Answer (score 2):

use following

```
List<File>tempList = Arrays.asList(temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the array and add each element to the list.

```
for (File each : temp)
  tempList.add(each);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a collections library call for this:

```
Arrays.asList(temp);
```