# How to make a copy of a file containing images and text using java

Tags: java, file, file-io, inputstream

I have some word documents and excel sheets which has some images along with the file text content. I want to create a copy of that file and keep it at a specific location. I tried the following method which is creating file at specified location but the file is corrupted and cannot be read.

```
InputStream document = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("upgradeworkbench/Resources/Upgrade_TD_Template.docx");
    try {
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Save");
        byte[] buffer= new byte[document.available()];
        document.read(buffer);
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setInitialFileName(initialFileName);
        if (flag) {
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Microsoft Excel Worksheet", "*.xls"));
        } else {
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Microsoft Word Document", "*.docx"));
        }
        fileChooser.setTitle("Save File");
        File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(stage);
        if (file != null) {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            outStream.write(buffer);
    //                            IOUtils.copy(document, outStream);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Can anyone suggest me any different ways to get the proper file.

PS: I am reading the file using `InputStream` because it is inside the project jar.

PPS: I also tried `Files.copy()` but it didnt work.

Comment: Think this has been already discussed here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433915/how-to-copy-file-from-one-location-to-another-location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you never trust on `InputStream.available` to know the real size of the input, because it just returns the number of bytes ready to be *immediately read* from the buffer. It might return a small number, but doesn't mean the file is small, but that the buffer is temporarily half-full.

The right algorithm to read an InputStream fully and write it over an OutputStream is this:

```
int n;
byte[] buffer=new byte[4096];
do
{
    n=input.read(buffer);
    if (n>0)
    {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
}
while (n>=0);
```

Comment: It works fine. Even the images are coming now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Files.copy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) methods.

> Copies all bytes from an input stream to a file. On return, the input stream will be at end of stream.

Comment: I tried that, but it dint accept the StandardCopyOption as CopyOption. Can you suggest me what to keep in place of CopyOptions?

Comment: The error message describes the issue: you're passing a File as the second parameter, it needs a Path.

Comment: Replace `file` with `file.toPath()`.

Comment: Thanx I missed this point. But my problem still stands. Still my new file is not properly created. The size is also less plus the content is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Files.copy(document, file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

As the class says, the second argument is a Path, not a File.

Generally, since this is 2015, use Path and drop File; if an API still uses File, make it so that it uses it at the last possible moment and use Path all the way.

Comment: I tried this way but still its giving a corrupted file.