# copy searched files to a specific location

Tags: java

i write a program that will search for files with the given extension in my PC. now i want to add one more thing to it. i wish that my program will copy these files into a specific location on my PC. here is my code sample :-

```
Finder(String pattern) 
    {
        matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
   }

    // Compares the pattern against
    // the file or directory name.
    void find(Path file) {
        Path name = file.getFileName();
        if (name != null && matcher.matches(name)) {
            System.out.println(file);
            String s = new String(name.toString());
            //System.out.println(s);
            File f = new File(s);
            //System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java)

Comment: i want to copy all the text files that resides in my PC, to my pendrive. my program is successfully searching for all text files and now i want to copy these.. how i can do this??

Comment: Check thread posted in comment above yours: you have only to choice the preferred way (based on you request about time, semplicity of code and so on).
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `FileInputStream`s for the files you want to copy, you can create `FileOutputStream`s outputting into the place you want to copy the files. Then, use a loop like the following to copy the file:

```
byte temp;
while ((temp = fileInputStream.read()) != -1)
    fileOutputStream.write(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick way to do it you can use the method [FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFileToDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) from Apache Commons IO.

Answer (score 0):

There are new great ways to walk the file tree with the FileVistitor interface. Click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html). After approaching a file that matches your criteria, move it using some high performanced new io:

```
public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File newDirectory) throws IOException {
    File destFile = new File(newDirectory, sourceFile.getName());
    if(!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    finally {
        if(source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if(destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Define the directory you want to move the files too in the parameter "newDirectory"

Answer (score 0):

There is no question in your question!
If you ask how to copy files, you have options:

- Use `java.nio.file.Files.copy()` method. This is preferred since you do not have to copy data yourself, can use Path and it is in standard library
- Use streams and copy data yourself as suggested by other answers
- There are other ways like invoking command on system to copy