# Copy file from one folder to another in Java

Tags: java, file-copying

I am trying to copy a file from one folder to another folder.

Here's what I have got in my code:

```
public static void copyFile(String path) throws IOException{
   newPath = path;    
   File destination = new File ("E:/QA/chart.js"); 
   FileUtils.copyFile(destination, new File(newPath));      
}
```

But it is not copying the desired file to its location.
What is required, its copy *chart.js* from E drive and copy to the *newPath* variable location.

Is there some other way to copy files from one place to another?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: You can find the answer by follow the below mention link
[Copy file from one directory to another][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java

Comment: Didn't you invert source and destination ?

Comment: no errors but file is not copying

Comment: @X.L.Ant : I think he did invert it.  Syntax FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(srcFile, destDir);

Comment: You may have a permissions issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use standard `java.nio.file.Files.copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
Path FROM = Paths.get(Your Source file complete path);
Path TO = Paths.get(Destination complete path);
CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
  StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
  StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES
}; 
java.nio.file.Files.copy(FROM, TO, options);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
FileUtils.copyFile(src, dest)
```

this is happening in copy.
so this point of view `File src = new File ("E:/QA/chart.js");` assume `src` file existing one.
Then you create a new destination file like this

```
File dest = new File(newPath);
if(!dest.exists())
  dest.createNewFile();
```

Then you can copy

```
FileUtils.copyFile(src,dest);
```

Comment: can i know value of **newPath**

Comment: actually my program will generate a folder which containing some files i just want to copy chart.js with that