# How to create a directory using File.getParentFile().getName() with relative path

Tags: java, file

I am having an input folder say `c:\files\input\` that contains my list of files that I am using.

How do I use the above to create say `c:\files\output\` and copy the files from the input folder to the output folder?

My `c:\files\input` is read from an `object`, say

```
String inputFolder = dataMap.getString("folder");// this will get c:\files\input\
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java

Its answered here

Comment: `new File(file.getParentFile(), "output")`?

Comment: Its been answered here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java

Comment: Yes I am using Java 7.

Comment: Do you want copy one directory contains list of files to another directory?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the best way but for my case I actually do have some logic, thus the copying of file should be immediately after logic is done.

Answer (score 1):

You got path of folder in variable `inputFolder` now do as follows.

```
String inputFolder = dataMap.getString("folder");

File dir = new File(inputFolder);
if(dir.mkdirs()){
    System.out.println("Directory created");
}else{
    System.out.println("Directory Not Created");
}
```

Comment: Some users are just jealous about you all having high reputation, maybe. I even have my own questions downvoted before. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FileUtils` from `org.apache.commons.io` library

```
FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
```

so in your case:

```
File file = new File(inputFolder);
String parentDir = file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
File outputDir = new File(parentDir, "output");
if(!outputDir.exsit()) {
    outputDir.mkdir();
}
FileUtils.copyDirectory(inputFolder, outputDir);
```

Answer (score 1):

To Create the directory you can refer to the below code

```
File file = new File("c:\\files\\output");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (file.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("Directory is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
            }
        }
```

To copy files from a directory to another directory.. refer to the following link it gives a good explanation with source code examples

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/file/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java/

Comment: Hi @Sandy_Chelsea, I don't want to "hardcode" the path as you had written File file = new File("c:\\files\\output");

Comment: if you dont want to hardcode populate the value from the Object you mentioned in your post like File file = new file(someObject.filepath);

Comment: This one is a duplicate answer.