# Copying files from directory to other using FileUtils jar

Tags: java, fileutils

I want to copy files from directory to another, so I searched and I got this post:
[Copying files from one directory to another in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java)

I follow the first answer, but I couldn't find the jar of FileUtils and the URL in the comments is broken.

Could you please help me to find the target jar?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

Comment: This is off-topic.  Stack Overflow is not a search engine.

Comment: Please read the Help Center before posting.

Comment: @David Wallace I searched on google and I got this link but I didn't find from where I can download the jar file. Sorry I don't use it before.

Comment: The page that I gave you the link for has two links on it that say "download now".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying files from one directory to another in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for commons-io, FileUtils is a class from apache's commons-io.jar

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the libary as mentioned but since Java7 there is a nice and quick way to do it with pure Java:

```
public static void copyDirectory(String input, String output) throws IOException {
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(input))) {
        for (Path entry: stream) {
            if (Files.isRegularFile(entry)) {
                Files.copy(entry, Paths.get(output).resolve(entry.getFileName()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you, but it moves the files not copy them??

Comment: @Eng.Lolina No, it only copies them. To move files you would have to use `Files.move()`

Comment: Yesssss, you are right. It was y mistake. Thanks very much.