# What am i doing wrong with copying my file?

Tags: java, io, apache-commons

So I am trying to copy one file from one place to the other using the solution found here :
[Copying files from one directory to another in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java)

My code creates the new directory but cant seem to find the file ,even though the landedtitlesFile is pointing to the proper path and file. I always get my "blast" comment in case you were wondering if my program gets to the end of the method.

Thank you for your time and patience.

```
private File landedtitlesFile = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\SteamApps\\common\\Crusader Kings II\\common\\landed_titles\\landed_titles.txt");
private String modPath = "C:\\Users\\Bernard\\Documents\\Paradox Interactive\\Crusader Kings II\\mod\\viking";


public void createCopyLandedTitles(Boolean vanilla){
    if (vanilla == true) {
        File dir = new File(modPath + "\\common\\landed_titles");
        dir.mkdir();
        try{
            FileUtils.copyFile(landedtitlesFile,dir);
        }
        catch (IOException e ){
            System.out.println("blast");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you check the exception? :|

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Comment: What does your `catch` block catch?

Comment: And _why_ does it catch an `IOException`? What is its _cause_?

Comment: @BURNS put the whole exception in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`copyFile`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) expects the second parameter to be the destination file, not a destination directory. You need to give it the target name of the file within that directory:

```
FileUtils.copyFile(
    landedtitlesFile,
    new File(dir, landedtitlesFile.getName());
```

Exception objects generally contain some information on the cause. If you print out the exception with `e.printStackTrace();` (or rethrow it up the stack with `throw new RuntimeException(e);`) then you will be able to see what it says.

Comment: Thank you very much ,you have been very helpful :)