# Copy one file from a folder to another folder in java

Tags: java, file, copy, directory

I am trying to copy a file form a folder to another folder

i have tried what was suggested in other posts but i have not been successful

[Copying files from one directory to another in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java?rq=1)

this has not worked for me

the file is C:/Users/win7/Desktop/G1_S215075820014_T111_N20738-A_D2015-01-26_P_H0.xml

the destination folder is C:/Users/win7/Desktop/destiny

this is the copy code

```
String origen = "C:/Users/win7/Desktop/G1_S215075820014"
               +"_T111_N20738-A_D2015-01-26_P_H0.xml";

String destino = "C:/Users/win7/Desktop/destiny";

private void copiarArchivoACarpeta(String origen, String destino) throws IOException {
    Path FROM = Paths.get(origen);
    Path TO = Paths.get(destino);
    CopyOption[] options =
            new CopyOption[] {StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
                StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES };
    java.nio.file.Files.copy(FROM, TO, options);
}
```

Comment: We can´t help you without knowing neither the error you are getting nor seeing any code.

Comment: private void copiarArchivoACarpeta(String origen, String destino) throws IOException{
   Path FROM = Paths.get(origen);
   Path TO = Paths.get(destino);
   CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
     StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
     StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES
   }; 
   java.nio.file.Files.copy(FROM, TO, options);
  }

Comment: I think the problem is you are trying to use `Files.copy` from a file to a folder destination instead of a file destination.

Comment: but that works to copy a file to another file not to a folder!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Standard concise way to copy a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java)

Comment: @AlexisZecharies Well it seems to work.. Are you sure you are not seeing a `destiny` file with no extensions under your `C:/Users/win7/Desktop/` path?

Comment: gtgaxiola that is what happens but what i want is to copy the file into the folder, which is not happening

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
java.nio.file.Files.copy(FROM, TO.resolve(FROM.getFileName()),
    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
```

Because the second parameter must be a Path to a file that not yet exists.

Just like the docu sais:
[image: Documentation]

Comment: yeeeeeeeees! sorry im not used to read the api from there thank you veryvery much i have spent the las 3 hours with this!