# How to copy a file in filesystem?

Tags: android

I would like to know the best way to copy a file in the filesystem? (android java function )

(sdcard/video/test.3gp -----> sdcard/video_bis/test2.3gp)

Is there an example somewhere?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

[Standard concise way to copy a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java)

Comment: This is not available without adding a lib/jar to android.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the file using standard Java I/O streams - there's nothing special you need to do.  Here's an [example](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html) on copying a file.  You might want to change the example so it's copying more than 1 byte at a time, though :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what you mean by best way of copying the file.

Since the file is on the sdcard you can use the normal java.io-package for reading and writing the file in the new place, as per Erich's answer.

Another option is [accessing the shell](http://code.google.com/p/market-enabler/wiki/ShellCommands), which I don't know if it will work, but which *might* be more efficient, since it uses the underlying system's cp-command.

In this case I assume that commands would only contain something like 
`"cp /sdcard/video/test.3gp /sdcard/video_bis/test2.3gp"`.

Even if this does work, I expect that this might stop working, since it really seems like a security issue in ways..

Comment: This makes more sense for what I *thought* you were asking about first, i.e. moving files. Perhaps that will teach me to think before answering.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
private static final String[] COMMAND = { "dd", "if=/sdcard/video/test.3gp", "of=/sdcard/video_bis/test2.3gp", "bs=1024" };

// ...

try {
    final Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(COMMAND);
    final int retval = pr.waitFor();
    if ( retval != 0 ) {
        System.err.println("Error:" + retval);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Works on the emulator, you should check if it works on your phone.