# Store audio in the directory of applications and way to get to use?

Tags: android, audio

I do not speak English! Please people ignore.
I want save audio from

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("audio/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                SELECT_PICTURE);
```

to other directories.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy a file in filesystem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246584/how-to-copy-a-file-in-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Intent tmpIntent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
 startActivityForResult(tmpIntent, 0);
```