# How to use getBytes()

Tags: java, file

So I m trying to create a method through which I will upload a File.But while creating a new file in this method I need to use getBytes() method.But I get error saying.

```
The method getBytes() is undefined for the type File
```

How can I overcome this??.Below is my method.

```
public String SomeFile(File file, String basePath, UrlInfoKey urlInfoKey) {
        LOG.info("basePath for back up is {}", basePath);
        String uploadedPath = null;
        String fileDetails = file.getName();
        String locationDetails = fileDetails;
        String locationFolderPath = basePath+"/"+locationDetails;
        File directory = new File(locationFolderPath);
        if(!directory.isDirectory()) {
            LOG.info("creating the directory at {}", locationFolderPath);
            directory.mkdir();
        }
        String filepath = locationFolderPath+"/"+file.getName().trim();
        LOG.info("file path to back up is {}",filepath);
        File creatingFile = new File(filepath);
        try {
            creatingFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(creatingFile);
            fos.write(file.getBytes());
            fos.close();
            uploadedPath = filepath;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info("could not create file ", e.getMessage());
        }
        uploadedPath= updateURLWithDBURL(urlInfoKey,uploadedPath);
        LOG.info("file uploaded at location {}",uploadedPath);
        return uploadedPath;
    }
```

```
Line:fos.write(file.getBytes());
```

Is where I m getting error.Is there any other alternative I could use.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Lara, This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520305/java-io-to-copy-one-file-to-another

Comment: Hi Pankaj,I saw the solution that you shared but I dont think so that's what i excatly want.If you have any other alternative for the problem in my code please do share it.Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using the old file io classes of Java instead of its modern API NIO revolving around `Files` and `Paths`? It is much simpler to use.

Comment: There is no such method as `File.getBytes()`. See the Javadoc. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a new file from the file uploaded you can use **createTempFile** of **java.io.File** class like:

```
*File newFile = File.createTempFile("desiredFileName"+ ":", "extension",
                            oldFile);*
```

Here *oldFile* is the uploaded file object.