# Copy and rename file on different location

Tags: java

I have one file **example.tar.gz** and I need to copy it to another location with different name 
example **_test.tar.gz**. I have tried with

```
private void copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile) throws IOException {

    InputStream oInStream = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
    OutputStream oOutStream = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] oBytes = new byte[1024];
    int nLength;

    BufferedInputStream oBuffInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(oInStream);
    while((nLength = oBuffInputStream.read(oBytes)) > 0) {
        oOutStream.write(oBytes, 0, nLength);
    }
    oInStream.close();
    oOutStream.close();
}
```

where

```
String from_path = new File("example.tar.gz");
File source = new File(from_path);

File destination = new File("/temp/example_test.tar.gz");
if(!destination.exists())
    destination.createNewFile();
```

and then

```
copyFile(source, destination);
```

It doesn't work. The path is correct. It prints that the file exists. Can anybody help me?

Comment: try `flush()` your streams before `close()` ing it.

Comment: Correct this code in your post: `String from_path=new File("example.tar.gz");`

Comment: @Mohamed, flush is never needed before close

Comment: you don't need createNewFile w/ FileOutputStream, also you should not use BufferedInputStream(), it doesn't really help. Just use larger than 1k `byte[] oBytes`. Last but not least, `FileChannel.transferTo` is the best way to copyStuff

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Why to reinvent the wheel, just use  [`FileUtils.copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile(java.io.File, java.io.File)) , this will handle many scenarios for you

Comment: works like a dream

Answer (score 8):

```
I would suggest Apache commons FileUtils or NIO (direct OS calls)
```

---

or Just this

Credits to Josh - [standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java/115086#115086)

---

```
File source=new File("example.tar.gz");
File destination=new File("/temp/example_test.tar.gz");

copyFile(source,destination);
```

---

Updates:

Changed to transferTo from @bestss

```
 public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
     if(!destFile.exists()) {
      destFile.createNewFile();
     }

     FileChannel source = null;
     FileChannel destination = null;
     try {
      source = new RandomAccessFile(sourceFile,"rw").getChannel();
      destination = new RandomAccessFile(destFile,"rw").getChannel();

      long position = 0;
      long count    = source.size();

      source.transferTo(position, count, destination);
     }
     finally {
      if(source != null) {
       source.close();
      }
      if(destination != null) {
       destination.close();
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Using FileStreams might be inefficient to copy files, look at `java.nio.channels.FileChannel.transferTo`

Answer (score 2):

There is `Files` class in package `java.nio.file`. You can use the `copy` method.

Example: `Files.copy(sourcePath, targetPath)`.

Create a targetPath object (which is an instance of `Path`) with the new name of your file.