# Duplicate file and rename with different file extension during runtime

Tags: java

I am trying to duplicate a csv file but rename the duplicated file with a new extension of txt during runtime so it can be used for another method. Can this be done?

Comment: You don't need java for this. You can  use `cp a.csv b.txt`.

Comment: @DeepakPatankar I am using windows. Also I would like to do this during runtime so the text file can be used in another method. I have edited the question.

Comment: please post what you have tried?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy and rename file on different location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388146/copy-and-rename-file-on-different-location)

Comment: @kasptom yes sorry my bad I have only come across this question now. Thanks for your help!