# Runtime.getRuntime.exec() problem with copying files

Tags: java

I want to copy a file using this :

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime()
     .exec("cmd.exe /c  copy  C:\test1\toto.PDF  C:\test2\toto.PDF");
```

When i execute the command manually, it works, but when i tried to do it from my IDE, nothing happened.
can someone tell me what is wrong with this please.

thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java - no need for exec.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to double the backslashes; `\t` by itself translates to a tab character.

(You were rather unlucky here, as if your path had been different, you might have got a compiler error that gave you a hint.)

Comment: Nice catch. I will remember it when I need to obfuscate some code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate error is that `\t` is a tab character.  You forgot to double the backslashes, so the file names got mangled.  However, as others have suggested, use [Commons IO-Utils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) to do the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a longer article about [pitfalls with runtime.exec](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?) 
Is `copy` a built-in of cmd.exe, or a separat executable?

I would cut the string into parts, to avoid misinterpretation of blanks/tabs:

```
"cmd.exe", "/c", "copy", "C:\test1\toto.PDF", "C:\test2\toto.PDF"
```

But this is all very platform dependend. You should read the file with java and write it to the target location.