# executing a java program in another java program using Runtime.exec() function

Tags: java, exec

The following code snippet i had given is using exec function and executes hello program (simple "hello world" printing java program). But as soon as i execute the main program, print statement of `instream.readline()` simply returns `NULL`. Please try to sort out the problem. Hope the explanation is clear.

CODE:

```
Process process2=null;
BufferedReader inStream=null; 
try
{
    process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java hello");
}
catch(IOException e1)
{
    System.err.println("Error on exec method");
    e1.printStackTrace();  
}
try
{
    inStream = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(process2.getInputStream() ));  
    System.out.println(inStream.readLine());
}
catch(IOException e1)
{
    System.err.println("Error on inStream.readLine()");
    e1.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your **hello.java** should be already compiled n **the class file should present in the current directory** where the program is located.

And for getting errors, you can get error stream from process class's object.

```
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));

String s="";
while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) 
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: thanks for replying....so do u mean, i can add the other satement::process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac hello.java");so as to get the hello.class file...and please note..i m working on eclipse IDE...not on command prompt,,where all the class files for my progrms are already available in bin directory of my project workspace.....

Comment: Hmm, I didn't tried it on an IDE. But you can achieve it by either of following ways:
1. using `javac <path_of_bin>/<file>.java` like this, with absolute/relative path
2. use `javac <file_name>.java` and 
then,  `move <file_name>.class <src_file>/<file_name>.class` and then try
`java <file_name>`

Comment: when m using the bin path..eclipse is raising errors..there's no such bin path usage in eclipse...and even i tried to move the hello.class file from bin directory of my project workspace into the src directory..however its still raising the error...""class file not found"""

Comment: try to use Absolute path. OR if you want to just testing the Runtime n Process class, then try to put that .class file into src folder.

Comment: Well, you can move the .class file from bin to src folder with the help of this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587643/runtime-getruntime-exec-problem-with-copying-files
And then execute java command.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Eclipse/java7/windows

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class ProcessDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println("current dir = " + dir);

        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr=run.exec("javac -d "+ dir +"\\src "+ dir+"\\src\\HelloDemo.java");

        pr.waitFor();

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        String s;

        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
                   while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) 
                        System.out.println(s);

        //read output
        while ((line=buf.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);

        pr.destroy();

        Runtime run1 = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr1=run1.exec("java -cp "+dir+"\\src HelloDemo");

        BufferedReader stdError1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr1.getErrorStream()));
        BufferedReader buf1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr1.getInputStream()));


        //interpretting file n executing it line by line :D :P

        pr1.waitFor();

        String temp;
        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("\n\nHere is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
                   while ((temp = stdError1.readLine()) != null) 
                        System.out.println(temp);

        //read output
        System.out.println(buf1.readLine());
        while ((temp=buf1.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(temp);


    }

}
```