# Runtime.getruntime().exec() doesn't work on Linux

Tags: java, linux, runtime, runtime.exec

I have a Java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` problem. I run my java app on Linux and just need to execute a basic task: copy and rename a file using `cp` command. However, it doesn't seem to work.

This is my chunk of code to call the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`:

```
String command = "cp -f '" + old_path + "' " + song_info[6] + ".mp3";                
System.out.println(command);
log.info(command);
            try{
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                int returnCode;
                try {
                    returnCode = p.waitFor();
                    System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Import.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            } catch(IOException e){log.error(e);}
```

When I run the java app the command for each loop is something like this

```
cp -f '/temp_storage/LoveSongs/28.I miss you.mp3' /music_storage/data/0/0/1/108.mp3
```

If I copy that log line and run it in the command line, it works perfectly. However the result from java app always return code 1 (which indicate failure). Even including `/bin/bash -c` before the command string, it still doesn't work.

Any suggestion why? I've just install JRE and JDK on that server. When I type 
`java -version` I got:

> java version "1.6.0_17" OpenJDK
>   Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.7.10)
>   (rhel-1.20.b17.el5-x86_64) OpenJDK
>   64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16,
>   mixed mode)

Comment: P/S: It didn't throw any sort of Exception.

Comment: have yout tried running this on any other O/S or just Linux?

Comment: @My Hed Hurts: I ran the similar task, calling the shell script file on another server and it runs normally. Only problem with this one.

Comment: Perhaps this was just a simple example of something more complicated you are trying to accomplish, but why would you fork a process to copy a file? It is relatively simple to do directly in java. The apache commons-io project even has [utility methods](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)) to make it even easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, if you command has multiple command line parameters you need to supply them in a String[], have you tried that? Furthermore if you need to copy files around you can use [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) or Guava libraries (dont remember what it's called there)

see this [relevant thread about copying files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java)

Comment: this is correct -- the system will try to find an executable called 'cp -f ...' rather than find an executable called 'cp' to which it passes the parameters '-f ...'

Answer (score 1):

Does the user that the application is running under have the necessary permissions? And from the process, have you tried getting hold of stderr to see if there is anything useful in there?

Comment: Thanks, but I ran the app under root account, and the files were chmod to 777