# FileInput/OutputStream versus FileChannels -- which gives better performance

Tags: java, performance, file, filestream, filechannel

I am writing a program that has to copy a sizeable, but not huge amount of data from folder to folder (in the range of several dozen photos at once).  Originally I was using `java.io.FileOutputStream` to simply read to buffer and write out, but then I heard about potential performance increases using `java.nio.FileChannel`.

I don't have the resources to run a serious, controlled test with the data I have, but there seems to be no consensus on what the advantages of each are (other than FileChannel being thread safe).  Some users report `FileChannel` being great for smaller files, others report huge speed increases with larger files.

I am wondering if anyone knows exactly what the intent of creating `FileChannel` was in the first place: was it designed for better performance?  In what cases?  And is there a definitive performance increase for general kinds of data, or are the differences I should expect to see trivial because I am not working with data that is specialized enough?

EDIT: Assume my data does not need to be thread safe.

Comment: Somewhat duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java.

Comment: Yes, similar questions have been asked many times, but I am well aware of the advanced IO packages out there.  I am more concerned right now with a raw performance comparison of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input and Output Streams assume a stream styled access to the file or resource.  There are a few extra items which help (array reads) but the basic idea is that of a stream where you read in one or more characters at a time (possibly blocking until you have more characters available).

Channels are the means to copy information into Buffers.  This provides a lower level of access to input and output routines.  With thoughtful buffer sizing, the speed-ups can be impressive.  Structuring your code around buffers can reduce the time spent in a read loop (also increasing performance).  Finally, while it is possible to do pre-checking of input stream state in an attempt to avoid blocking, Channels and Buffers allow operations to perform in a non-blocking manner (even in the worst conditions).

Answer (score 2):

`FileChannel.transferFrom/To` should be faster than IO stream for file copying.

Or you can simply use Java 7's [`java.nio.file.Files.copy(source, target)`](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29). That should be as fast as it can get.

However, in the end, performance won't be noticeably different - hard disk speed is the bottleneck.

---

`FileChannel` is not non-blocking, and it is not selectable. Not sure if they are going to add these features in future.  Java 7 has `AsynchronousFileChannel` though.

Comment: I wanted to add that, depending on implementation, a `transferXXX()` operation can be a lot faster because the data isn't copied between kernel and user-space in memory.

Comment: It should be, as it claimed - it would be a shame if this API is not at least not slower than stream API. Yet shame it is, many people report it is indeed slower in many situations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you take a look at `commons-io`?

```
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(srcFile, destDir);
```

Comment: I have no real need for that much IO functionality.  This is not an IO heavy program, there is just one operation once in a while that happens to copy lots of files and needs to be fast.

Comment: That's why I mentioned it. IO performance depends a lot from the buffering strategy. The library is available for years, with continuous updates and lots of programming hours spent to it. I assume it performs better than own implementations, even when a certain amount is spent to it.