# Overwriting database file with another non-empty one

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying this to overwrite the file:

```
File file = new File(importDir, dbFile.getName());
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(
new FileOutputStream(file, false));                 
output.close();
```

But it obviously overwrites an old file with an new empty one, and my goal is to owerwrite it with the content provided by `file`

How do I do that correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my purposes it seems that the easiest way is to delete file and then copy it

```
            if (appFile.exists()) {
                appFile.delete();
                appFile.createNewFile();
                this.copyFile(backupFile, appFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, such simple operation as file copying is unobvious in Java.

In Java 7 you can use NIO util class [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) as follows:

```
Files.copy(from, to);
```

Otherwise its harder and instead of tons of code, better read this carefully [Standard concise way to copy a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java)

Comment: Android is not comparable to Java 7, and does not appear to have java.nio.file

Comment: I didn't take into account android tag

Answer (score 0):

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str;
    System.out.print("Enter a file name to copy : ");
    str = br.readLine();

    int i;
    FileInputStream f1;
    FileOutputStream f2;

  try
  {
    f1 = new FileInputStream(str);
    System.out.println("Input file opened.");
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException e)
  {
    System.out.println("File not found.");
    return;
  }

  try
  {
    f2 = new FileOutputStream("out.txt");    //    <---   out.txt  is  newly created file
    System.out.println("Output file created.");
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException e)
  {
    System.out.println("File not found.");
    return;
  }

  do
  {
    i = f1.read();
    if(i != -1) f2.write(i);
  }while(i != -1);
  f1.close();
  f2.close();
  System.out.println("File successfully copied");
```

Comment: i hav not read about database file in your question,  so I posted this answer here

Comment: try it, I hav not checked it with database file

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutpurStream(file);
>
> fos.write(string.getBytes());

constructor which will create the new file or if exists already then overwrite it...

Comment: yeah well... there is no string to getBytes on it

Comment: i think you can't copy directly file.. instead you have to read it line by line and write it to other file...