# exception during file copy in Java

Tags: java, file-copying

I have a function that copies binary file

```
    public static void copyFile(String Src, String Dst) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File f1 = new File(Src);
    File f2 = new File(Dst);
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

and the second function

```
    private String copyDriverToSafeLocation(String driverPath) {
    String safeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
    String safeLocation = safeDir + "\\my_pkcs11tmp.dll";
    try {
        Utils.copyFile(driverPath, safeLocation);
        return safeLocation;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured while copying driver: " + ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The second function is run for every driver found in the system.
The driver file is copied and I am trying to initialize PKCS11 with that driver.
If initialization failed I go to next driver, I copy it to the tmp location and so on.

The initialization is in try/catch block
After the first failure I am no longer able to copy next driver to the standard location.

I get the exception

```
Exception occured while copying driver: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Norbert\my_pkcs11tmp.dll (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
```

How can I avoid the exception and safely copy the driver file?

For those curious why am I trying to copy the driver ... PKCS11 has nasty BUG, which prevents using drivers stored in the location that has "(" in the path ... and this is a case I am facing.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank all of you for your comments. I don't want to use extra libraries like apache as finally this code is to be run by applet. All the rest I tried, but it seems that dest file is in use. I even tried nasty solution and enumerated drivers (and added the number to dst file name), but when I run this by applet dst file is in use, when the applet is run more then once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is used by an other process and locked, there is no generic solutions to be able to access it. You best chance is to use [FileLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) but it's plateform-dependant, read the documentation, it's written that the results are "advisory", so be carefull. you can also take a look at the [ReentrantReadWriteLock class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would move the try-catch block into the `copyFile` method. That way you can properly handle closing the `InputStream`s (which is probably causing the JVM to hold onto the file handle). Something like this:

```
public static void copyFile(String Src, String Dst) {
    try {
        File f1 = new File(Src);
        File f2 = new File(Dst);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured while copying driver: " + ex);
    }
    finally {
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Then you can remove the try-catch from the `copyDriverToSafeLocation` method.

Answer (score 1):

Or there's the Java 7 Way:

```
public static void copyFile(String src, String dst) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(src))) {
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dst))) {
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      int len;
      while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: And the Java 7 NIO way.

```
public static void copyFile(String src, String dst) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  copyFile(new File(src), new File(dst));
}

public static void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(src)) {
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst)) {
      copyFile(in, out);
    }
  }
}

public static void copyFile(FileInputStream in, FileOutputStream out) throws IOException {
  FileChannel cin = in.getChannel();
  FileChannel cout = out.getChannel();
  cin.transferTo(0, cin.size(), cout);
}
```

Comment: You don't close() your Input or Output streams.

Comment: They don't need to be explicitly closed in java 7. They are automagically closed when the try block ends.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose to go with Apache Commons IO and their FileUtils.copyFile() routine(s).

[Standard concise way to copy a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why a problem with one file would prevent copying a *different* file. However, not closing a file when an exception occurs could definitely cause problems. Use try...finally to make sure you call close on every file you open.