# shell command programmatically that don't work

Tags: java, android, shell

i'm tring to copy one file by one directory to another. i'm using the "cp" function. this is the code

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp "+path+" "+destinationFolder);
```

this code work well on many device but in other i get this error

```
error running exec(cp, /data/app/myApp.apk, mnt/sdcard/destinationFolder.
```

working directory null, envinroment null. caused by ioException permission denied why i'm getting this error and how can i solve? any help is

Comment: Well... here's a workaround: copy the file [programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496732/copy-file-from-the-directory-to-another-having-the-paths-of-file-and-director)

Answer (score 1):

> error running exec(cp, /data/app/myApp.apk, mnt/sdcard/destinationFolder

Looks your destination path lacks root slash as it should be `/mnt/sdcard/destinationFolder` not `mnt/sdcard/destinationFolder` as quoted error message indicates

Comment: And not sure how you build destinationFolder really, but you should be using `getExternalStorageDirectory()`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: No, this not solve the problem. but the command "cp" require root access?

Answer (score 0):

This error could be vendor dependant, obviously the error is lack of permissions when trying to copy the files in /data/app/, most of the devices won't let you do that unless the device is rooted and you are using sudo commands, if you are trying to attack a global market with your application I'm sure you will have a lot of problems with that, and you should find a better approach.

Hope this Helps

Regards!

Comment: If you are trying to copy a file that requires root permissions yes, otherwise no, that's why it might work on some phones because some vendors might have different permissions stated

Comment: i'm tring to copy an apk file by it's folder to another folder in sdcard. this require root access?

Comment: It might, but now that you mention it, are you sure you have the "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" set in your manifest?

Comment: Yes, this permessions is set in my manifest. i don't understand if the cp function require root access or not. i tested on my rooted phone and it works but in NON rooted phone i get the error that is in the question, so this "cp" command require root access?

Comment: cp will require root access IF and only IF the file you are trying to copy requires root permissions, is not the command "cp" itself the one that needs the permissions but the file you are trying to copy