# Merging two folders with priority on timestamp

Tags: java, copy

One of our teams recently migrated a good deal of legacy data to a folder with all of the current data. Some of the team members weren't aware of the changes, so they continued to make modifications in the legacy folder.

I'd like to consolidate the data by doing timestamp checks. I can write a script for this, but I essentially want to do a windows explorer merge of two folders, where the option selected is always the "newer" one in conflicts. That is, if the source has the newer file, copy the source into the dest. If the dest is newer, don't copy the source into the dest. If the source exists but the dest doesn't, copy the source over.

I'm writing a quick script in Java, but I'm running into some issues, and I wanted to know if there's a much simpler solution to simply always select the "newer" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy file [Standard concise way to copy a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java)

To get timestamp http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29

Comment: Yup, thanks for the quick response! I'm looking at the links, and I'm writing the script now. I just thought there may have been a simpler way to do this, since Windows Explorer already checks for the timestamp and it tells the client which file is newer.

Comment: Your Welcome. In that way you need to include the classes to read Windows Timestamp.But This looks little better and Perfomance wise you dont need include extra classes as answer has already more than 100 Upvote It should Give you Better Result ..