# Move files to a certain directory

Tags: java

How do I make it so that certain files move to a certain directory and log it as failed?
The files are saved locally and I would like to move them around locally too.
What are the commands or statements in java to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Javadoc for `Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html). It has move methods which throw exceptions on failure.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look specifically at the following [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html). The reason why I say that is because Java 7 (within the `java.nio.*` [package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html)) provides new File I/O APIs that are much more versatile than previous Java versions.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/115086/4850

As for errors, in the `try/finally` block of the second answer of the above link, code a `catch` block  which does the logging.