# Is there any way of copying an image file in Android that does not involve compressing it?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, compression, copying

Is there any way of copying an image file in Android that does not involve compressing it? 
That is, I would like to store the exact same picture in both places, same height, width, size, and properties.

I tried using copyBitmap, createBitmap (Bitmap src), but neither of these writes to android.

From my research I only found code similar to:

Bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream), which is not something I want. This either loses quality, or explodes the size of the picture at least 2 fold.

Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: do you have already a copy of this image in the sdcard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Standard concise way to copy a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, all you have to do is to use the java.io libraries, because you don't want to do image processing but file operations. It could look like this:

```
private void copy(File soure, File destination) throws IOException {
    Reader reader = new FileReader(soure);
    Writer writer = new FileWriter(destination);

    while (reader.ready()) {
        writer.write(reader.read());
    }
}
```