# Java copying an ogg file to another file

Tags: java, file, file-io, directory, ogg

This is my first time asking a question but I hope I can get an answer. I am trying to copy an existing resource (ogg file) to another directory. I have had success with reading the file as an AudioInputStream and playing the file, but I cannot figure out how to write the file to another location. I am using vorbisspi, tritonus, jorbis, and jogg. (they all came with the vorbisspi library). Can someone please provide an example of a code to write an ogg file to another directory starting with the reading of the file as a resource? If you use any libraries, please specify. Thanks for your help.

Comment: step back and realize that an .ogg file is a **FILE**. Don't look for "how to copy an ogg file". Look for "copy a file"... which will be a bedrock core function...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Standard concise way to copy a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java)

Comment: I thought sound files were different than txt files and such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  srcFile  and dstFile according to your requirement. Increase buffer size (currently 1024) if required. 
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;

```
public class FileCopy {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File srcFile = new File("/home/test001/sampleDir/sourcefile.wav");

        File dstFile = new File("/home/test001/sampleDir/dstFile.wav");
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What is wrong with using `Files.copy`?

Comment: Thank you SOOO much, I had no idea it was this simple, I would upvote you but I don't have enough reputation apparently!! Thank you so much!
I thought writing an ogg file would be different for some reason. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Java API: [Files.copy(Path, Path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29)

Answer (score 0):

Copying file from one location to another has nothing to do with formats, codecs etc.

Solution:

1. Add Apache Commons IO library to your project.
2. Add one line of code:

   ```
   FileUtils.copyFile(src, dst);
   ```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I did not realize that all files could be copied the same. I thought sounds and were different.