# Windows: moving a file that was previously mapped in memory fails

Tags: java, linux, windows, file-io

## -:= EDITED TO SIMPLIFY =:-

I am facing an issue in the process of porting code from a Linux (Ubuntu LTS 12.4) environment to Windows Server 2008.

I need to use memory mapped file but I am not able to prevent the error below on Windows.

This issue is reproduced in the unit test below. The 2 tests are succeeding on Linux but on Windows the test **testWithRandowmAccessFile** fails with the stack trace on the bottom.

What is the root cause of the **testWithRandowmAccessFile** test failing?
How am I supposed to implement that on Windows?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestIOOnWindows {   

    @Test
    public void testWithRandowmAccessFile() throws IOException {
        final File sourceFile = new File("source.txt");
        final File manipulatedFile = new File("manipulated.txt");
        final File targetFile = new File("target.txt");

        try
        (
            FileInputStream sourceInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            RandomAccessFile manipulated = new RandomAccessFile(manipulatedFile, "rw");
            FileChannel fcOut = manipulated.getChannel()
        ) 
        {
            byte[] sourceBytes = new byte[Long.valueOf(sourceFile.length()).intValue()];
            IOUtils.read(sourceInputStream, sourceBytes);

            final int length = sourceBytes.length;            

            // ========= with this single line on Windows, the move fails ======
            MappedByteBuffer byteBuffer = fcOut.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, length);
            // commenting this line would not prevent the error on Windows
            byteBuffer.put(sourceBytes, 0, length);            
        }

        Files.move(
                Paths.get(manipulatedFile.getAbsolutePath()),
                Paths.get(targetFile.getAbsolutePath()),
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithFileOutputStream() throws IOException {
        final File sourceFile = new File("source.txt");
        final File manipulatedFile = new File("manipulated.txt");
        final File targetFile = new File("target.txt");

        try
        (
            FileInputStream sourceInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            FileOutputStream manipulatedOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(manipulatedFile);
            FileChannel fcIn = sourceInputStream.getChannel();
            FileChannel fcOut = manipulatedOutputStream.getChannel()
        ) 
        {
            final long length = sourceFile.length();

            // ========= with this single line on Windows, the move succeed ====
            fcIn.transferTo(0, length, fcOut);
        }

        Files.move(
                Paths.get(manipulatedFile.getAbsolutePath()),
                Paths.get(targetFile.getAbsolutePath()),
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

adding the tack trace I am getting when running the unit test from command prompt on windows.

```
There was 1 failure:
1) testWithRandowmAccessFile(TestIOOnWindows) java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\manipulated.txt -> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\target.txt: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Unknown Source)
    ===> at TestIOOnWindows.testWithRandowmAccessFile(TestIOOnWindows.java:40) <===
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:98)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMainAndExit(JUnitCore.java:53)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:45)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 2,  Failures: 1
```

Comment: You have to close all InputStream and RandomAccessFile after use.

Comment: @vzamanillo, all streams are closed as far I can see.  Any Closable stream is inside a try with resource block . Did I miss one?

Comment: if I don't use the MappedByteBuffer, thus if I don't load the FileChannel (fcIn) into memory, but I write the file directly to to the RandomAccessFile then the test succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, file mappings are garbage collected, and there is no supported way to forcibly destroy a mapping.

From the [`FileChannel.map()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29) documentation:

> The buffer and the mapping that it represents will remain valid until
>   the buffer itself is garbage-collected.
>
> A mapping, once established, is not dependent upon the file channel
>   that was used to create it.  Closing the channel, in particular, has
>   no effect upon the validity of the mapping.

In Sun's JDK, you can test that this is indeed the culprit by forcibly destroying the mapping just before doing the file move:

```
import sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer;
import sun.misc.Cleaner;
[...]
if (byteBuffer.isDirect()) {
    Cleaner cleaner = ((DirectBuffer) byteBuffer).cleaner();
    cleaner.clean();
}
// move file
```

Comment: you're right. Thanks that's the explanation. The buffer was direct and cleaning it prevent the error. THX

Comment: @AntoineWils: note that `sun.*` interfaces are unsupported, will probably not work in JDKs other than Sun's and OpenJDK, and may break at any time in the future without warning.

Comment: In other words, I provided the code example for demonstration purposes, and not for use in production environments.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will not use it in production. For the story, while testing solutions for this isuue we figured out that with nio2 it is fster to seek on a RandomAccessFile than using memory mapped file

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all. Windows can't delete or rename an open file like any Unix can, and you're opening `workFile` and then immediately trying to rename it. You'll have to close the stream first.

Comment: I think I am closing everything possible as I am commenting above. Could you please show me what you mean? Maybe you could make the unit test succeed

Comment: @AntoineWils I'm not going to go find a Windows machine so I can prove something on a dare. Post the actual error you're getting (the stack trace, not just a summary).

Comment: I added the stack trace. Your answer is correct but the real issue is that I am not able to spot what I should change in the unit test to make it succeed. Do you see any place where a stream is still open?

Comment: @AntoineWills Based on the stack trace, I'm suspecting that the file is open somewhere else, possibly in another unit test. Note that your test for the existence of the file (deleting if *not* present?) looks like a semantic bug; perhaps your test should be failing there.

Comment: you‘re right the delete semantics are buggy. But they are not involved in the issue because added after the bug was reproduced in the test method.<br/>The file cannot be opened somewhere else. The test is compiled and run standalone via command line. Is it possible that Windows holds a file handle in the background when the code does not anymore?