# unable to execute terminal command from java code

Tags: java, command-line

I want to execute terminal commands,for example `cp`, from within the java program. The code that I am trying is:

```
    public String executeCommand(){
Process p;
    String[] str = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "cp", "/Users/Desktop/abc.csv",  "/Users/Desktop/folder1/"};
            try {

                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);
            //p.waitFor();
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(output.toString());
            return "Success";
    }
```

The code executes without error but I do not see file copied at the destination. I also tried to have a single `String` with the above command instead of having an array but still no success. If I remove `/bin/bash` then I get error as `cannot find cp: no such file or directory`.

What am I doing wrong here and how to resolve it?

**NOTE:** I think that the command is not executed at all as if I for above copy example, even if I give an invalid file location, it does not throw any error and executes like as before without actually executing the command.

**UPDATE:** I was able to execute cp command by using `/bin/cp` followed by source and destination. But if I try to execute a command like hadoop fs -put then it does not work. I am trying to execute `/usr/bin/hadoop fs -put`. I get error as `could not find or load main class fs`,
 **How do I execute hadoop fs commands**?

Comment: you get output by putting **readLine()** then you can find the problem

Comment: @fastsnail I tried that way also but same result as before. I have edited my post above to include `readline()`. I do not see anything on my intellij console accept the success message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cannot find cp: no such file or directory.` - means that cp not found. Try to specify full path e.g. `/bin/cp`.

The bash command expects a single argument for `-c`, however you are passing three of them. Try to pass it in same piece, i.e. `{"/bin/bash", "-c", "cp /Users/Desktop/abc.csv /Users/Desktop/folder1/"}`.

Alternatively, try some other more concise solution, e.g. [Standard concise way to copy a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java)

Comment: I tried `{"/bin/bash", "-c", "cp /Users/Desktop/abc.csv /Users/Desktop/folder1/"}` and also `{"/bin/cp", "-c", "cp /Users/Desktop/abc.csv /Users/Desktop/folder1/"}` but both time same result. It executes without error but nothing gets copied.

Comment: I think that the command is not executed at all as if for above copy example, even if I give an invalid file location, it does not throw any error and executes like as before without actually executing the command.

Comment: @user2966197 Have you tried `/bin/cp`? Have you checked `getErrorStream()`? Usually error messages are printed into stderr, not stdout.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to execute `cp` command by using `/bin/cp` followed by source and destination. But if I try to execute a command like `hadoop fs -put` then it does not work. I am trying to execute `/usr/bin/hadoop fs -put`.