# Convert *.txt file to *.py file in Java?

Tags: java, file, file-conversion

If I have a standard txt file and I'm reading it in using either FileInputStream or FileReader, how can I convert that into a .py file using Java?

Comment: This makes no sense.  How do you turn arbitrary text into Python source code?

Comment: Do you have to read it in via a stream or reader?

Comment: If you are simply asking how to copy a file with a different name in Java, that has been asked and answered many time before.

Comment: Ditto for renaming a file.

Comment: Probable duplicate of this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java

Comment: Wow... looking back on this after these years, I have **absolutely** no idea what I was trying to do here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to read the file. All you have to do is change the file name:

```
File txtFile = new File("somefile.txt");
File pyFile = new File("somefile.py");
txtFile.renameTo(pyFile);
```