# Make a cloned jar file of itself

Tags: java, security

hey guys i just make some changes to the previous one ....
      that is

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
public class Test1234{
          public static void main(String args[]){
                   File inputF = new File(Test1234.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile());
                    File outputF = new File("D:\\test.class");
                    FilePermission adb = new FilePermission(inputF.getPath(),"write,read,execute");
                    Files.copy(inputF.toPath(),outputF.toPath(),REPLACE_EXISTING);
           }
     }

       for simplicity the inputF points to the class file itself. And it compiles perfect. but when i found the file  test.class it only is an empty folder.
```

so please guys help me !!! I'm stuck with this problem.

Comment: You should add the exception stack trace.

Comment: Could you post any stacktraces?

Comment: So now you have broken the layout again that others had fixed for you?

Comment: don't get me wrong guys but still i dont understand the solution ..... it will be great if you rewrite my code with a solution.

Comment: `read` should read `read()` in order to compile. I just edited formatting of the code.

Comment: This might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java/16600787#16600787

Comment: i just make some changes but still have other problem - have found an output but it's an empty folder.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for the permission denied is that you cannot write to `C:\` as the current user. Chose a folder you can write to or run as administrator.

Since you are running a plain `main` method there is very probably no `SecurityManager`, plus you would get a `SecurityException` if that was the problem. Also, it does not matter whether you *read* the current code source, only on Windows you cannot *delete* or *write* to it since this would be locked by the OS.

If that is not the problem, you need to verify `Test1234.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()` points to what you actually want to copy. A stack trace would help in that case.

Comment: i am sure that it is not the problem of writing to c:\ or other.... i know that its the problem of copying the sourcode of itself to another file.

Comment: and hey simon i just replace the getPath() to getFile() but still remained with the same problem.

Comment: `openStream` would make more sense than `getFile`.

Answer (score 0):

i just found out the solution by building my class file to jar file. then when i run it, it created a cloned jar file named test.jar.  by when i just say this one you must change the outputF path to "d:\test.jar".  :)