# How to copy file from one folder to another in Grails

Tags: grails

I am working with Grails. I need to copy a file from one folder to another. Here are my attempts below ::

```
def wrapAll(){
    def uploadList = Upload.findAllByIsWrapped(false)
    if (uploadList){
        uploadList.each {
            def dist = new Dist(it.properties)
            dist.filePath = it.filePath.replace("upload","dist")
            def file = new File(it.filePath)

        }
    }
}
```

here it.filePath = web-app/apps/upload/test_txt_file.txt and
dist.filePath = web-app/apps/dist/test_txt_file.txt

I want that first file will be copied in second location.

Comment: have you tried this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java  or this ? http://www.journaldev.com/861/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java

Comment: @vahid nice link , thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below copies files the groovy way. Try this after injecting *grailsApplication*.

```
def source = grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource("dirLoc1/inputFile.json").file
def destination = grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource("dirLoc2/outputFile.json").file
destination.createNewFile()

destination.withDataOutputStream { os ->
    source.withDataInputStream { is -> 
        os << is 
    }
}
```