# Put specific image in folder from resource

Tags: java

I need put one specific image from my project to specific folder in Java. Thanks for helping.

Edit:
Im creating a folder with File and the folder I'm creating i need to put an image i have in resources. Thanks for helping.

Comment: drop to your src folder and refresh?

Comment: The question still isn't clear. You want to copy an image in your app as a resource to a location in the filesystem?

Comment: If I well understood , he just want to move/copy an image from a folder to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NIO package in Java 7 with the class `Files` and the static method `copy`.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class Main_copie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Path source = Paths.get("data/image1.png");
        Path destination = Paths.get("MyFolder/image1_copied.png");

        try {
            Files.copy(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);   
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to copy the file from 1 location to another? If so, then the approach would be to create a new `File` at the desired location, create a `FileOutputStream` and write everything from the original File (using an `FileInputStream`) to this OutputStream.

Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java) can help you out.