# Something similar to FileCopyUtils.copy method in basic Java

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to generate a pdf in my application.

I have used the following in a previous project to copy the byte array to the outputstream.

```
FileCopyUtils.copy(fileContent, response.getOutputStream());
```

In my current project we are not using spring framework. So I cannot use `FileCopyUtils` here. Is there any other way to do the similar thing in simple basic java.

Comment: Check `FileCopyUtils` source for guidance

Comment: Did you say `fileContent` is a byte array?

Comment: @immibis yeah in my case..

Comment: See also [Standard concise way to copy a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write a byte array to an `OutputStream`, call its `write` method:

```
response.getOutputStream().write(fileContent);
```

No helper methods required.

Answer (score 2):

Class [`java.nio.file.Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) contains several utility methods to copy files (new since Java 7).

For example:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Somewhere\\Somefile.txt");

Files.copy(path, response.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: does this actually do the trick? I just need to copy the converted pdf byte array. It is not a file loaded from any location.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must do it yourself (I would strongly recommend you do not) then something like this should work.

```
public static void copy(Reader in, Writer out) throws IOException {
  final char[] buffer = new char[4096];
  int read;
  do {
    read = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    if (read > 0) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
  } while (read >= 0);
}
```