# How to save a file using FileChooser in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, filechooser

How to save a file using FileChooser from JavaFX,
here's my sample:

```
public static void clickDownloadButton(String filename,Stage window){
   File file = new File(filename);
   FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
   fileChooser.setTitle("Save file");
   fileChooser.showSaveDialog(window);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Standard concise way to copy a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java) BTW: sillyfly's answer already mentiones the IMHO best approach

Comment: The problem with the linked question is that IMHO the answers are overly-complicated (because they are outdated/before NIO was widely used? I don't know). using `Files.copy` is very simple, and I don't see a reason to mess around with streams or use external dependencies when it exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`java.nio.file.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) -

```
File dest = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(window);
if (dest != null) {
    try {
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), dest.toPath());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle exception...
    }
}
```

Comment: would you explain your code please? I don't understand what does this line do. `Files.copy(file.toPath(), dest.toPath());` in [docs.oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm) they have done in different way.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) for the method. It copies the file given by the first argument to the path given by the second argument.

Comment: from documentation "By default, the copy fails if the target file already exists or is a symbolic link, except if the source and target are the same file, in which case the method completes without copying the file" I want failure when the file exist, then which function should I use?

Comment: If you want the operation **not** to succeed if the target already exists then just use this method. If you want to **replace** existing files use the `REPLACE_EXISTING` option, as described in the documentation.

Comment: "....just use this method..." which function? `Files.copy()`? But it always takes argument.