# Java clone jpg without losing quality of image

Tags: java, image, copy

I have following method for coping jpg photos from one folder to another:

```
public static void copyImage(String from, String to) {
    try {
        File sourceimage = new File(from);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(sourceimage);
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(to));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImgLib.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NullPointerException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(ImgLib.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }       
}
```

It works, but little bit loosing quality of photo.

How I can achieve "perfect" cloning without loosing quality?

Comment: Why do you read/write as **image**? Why not just copying the file as such? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java/106807#106807

Comment: @AndreasFester, thank you, I tried, and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. In this line:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(to));
```

Your method is still re-encoding the image data which, with a lossy format like JPEG, will inevitably cause a loss of fidelity in the image.

I think, you may try to copy the image file using this code:

```
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/img/src"));
        os = new FileOutputStream(new File("path/to/img/dest"));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
```

Also, you may Apache Commons IOUtils to simplify copying from one stream to the other or if you are using Java 8 then you can just call [Files.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/img/src"));
            os = new FileOutputStream(new File("path/to/img/dest"));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used BufferedImage which read the file into a image object. 
instead you should read and write image file in the same way as you do with binary files (use InputStraem and OutputStream).