# How to copy and save file which user chosen with FileChooser in javafx

Tags: java, file, javafx

I am making program where user can choose image with FileChooser and display it in program. But i want to save all the images in my folder. I want to store all the images there. So is there any option if user choose image which is on desktop to make a copy of that image and paste it in my folder?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24333657/4185959

Answer (score 1):

Well im not entirely sure about your implementation and how you are presenting the opened image in your program but taking oracles example from here : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm

its fairly simple to make the program copy the selected files to a certain direction using javaNIO:

```
private void openFile(File file) {
        try {
            File dest = new File("C:\\Users\\yourProfile\\Desktop"); //any location
            Files.copy(file.toPath(), dest.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(
                FileChooserSample.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex
                );
        }
    }
```

You can test this with the example application i linked earlier:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class FileChooserSample extends Application {

    private Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("File Chooser Sample");

        final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        final Button openButton = new Button("Open a Picture...");
        final Button openMultipleButton = new Button("Open Pictures...");

        openButton.setOnAction(
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
                    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
                    if (file != null) {
                        openFile(file);
                    }
                }
            });

        openMultipleButton.setOnAction(
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
                    List<File> list =
                        fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
                    if (list != null) {
                        for (File file : list) {
                            openFile(file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        final GridPane inputGridPane = new GridPane();

        GridPane.setConstraints(openButton, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(openMultipleButton, 1, 0);
        inputGridPane.setHgap(6);
        inputGridPane.setVgap(6);
        inputGridPane.getChildren().addAll(openButton, openMultipleButton);

        final Pane rootGroup = new VBox(12);
        rootGroup.getChildren().addAll(inputGridPane);
        rootGroup.setPadding(new Insets(12, 12, 12, 12));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(rootGroup));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    private void openFile(File file) {
        try {
            desktop.open(file);
            File dest = new File("C:\\Users\\yourprofile\\Desktop");
            Files.copy(file.toPath(), dest.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(
                FileChooserSample.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex
                );
        }
    }
}
```

You just have to modify the directory, note however there are many ways and implementations of copying files depending on which version of java you are using and whether or not you are using other libraries such as apache io.

Other links that may be useful if you are using a standard file method :

[JavaPractices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=246)   [JavaCodeGeek](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/file/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java/)   [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java)

Hope that helps in anyway :) good luck with your program.