# How to copy file in resource folder in java

Tags: java, file

Need a quick help. I am new to Java..In my project I have input & output folder in resources. Inside input folder I have a csv file. I need to move that file to output folder through java code. How to copy that input file to output directory. I have tried in google but not getting a working solution. My project structure is based on standard maven project.

Comment: Is this a maven question? Do you want to copy the file during a build?

Comment: Basically I have to copy that file from input folder to output folder. How to do that?

Comment: No. I want to do this through java coding

Comment: I would try googling, or searching here on stackoverflow. Copying a file using Java is a solved problem.

Comment: But not from one resource folder to another. I was getting Nullpointer while trying other solution

Comment: Try a little bit of googling like Paul suggested. Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have a look in the "Related" column on the right. The second suggestion for me is "[Standard consise way to copy a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java?rq=1)". Would that help?

Comment: @BalwinderSingh tried almost 2 days..Still no luck

Comment: @PaulHicks No it did not helped

Comment: @SujataRoy share the relevant code and explain what part isn't working and what is the error you are getting. Go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask links and then update your question accordigly

Comment: sure let me share the code

Comment: ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("/input").getFile());

    Path path = Paths.get("/output");

    Files.copy(file.toPath(), path,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

Comment: This is the code.. I am getting nul pointer while trying to get output folder absolute path

Comment: You need to share the code in the question itself. Also sharing the code won't help until you share the error and your observations. Like I said go through  stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask links and then update your question accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I think there are at least four methods you can use to move your csv file to some other directory.

I assume that you already know the **absolute directory path**.

**Method 1. The way of apache commons**

You can use apache commons io library.

```
public static void moveWithApacheCommonsIO()
    {
        File sourceFile = new File("resource/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv");
        File destinationFile = new File("resource/aa/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv");

        try {
            FileUtils.moveFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Method 2. The way of java's NIO**

You can also use nio (non-blocking io) in java

```
public static void moveWithFileNIO()
    {
        File sourceFile = new File("resource/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv");
        File destinationFile = new File("resource/aa/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv");
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

        sourceFile.deleteOnExit();

        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final FileChannel inChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
        final FileChannel outChannel = outputStream.getChannel();

        try {
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                inChannel.close();
                outChannel.close();
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

**Method 3. The traditional way of java's IO**

You can use traditional method with file in and output stream in java.(Blocking IO)

```
public static void moveWithFileInOutStream()
    {
        File sourceFile = new File("resource/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv");
        File destinationFile = new File("resource/aa/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv");
        InputStream fin = null;
        OutputStream fout = null;

        sourceFile.deleteOnExit();

        try {
            fin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
            fout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationFile));

            byte[] readBytes = new byte[1024];
            int readed = 0;


            while((readed = fin.read(readBytes)) != -1)
            {
                fout.write(readBytes, 0, readed);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                fin.close();
                fout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

**Method 4. Using JNI(Java Native Interface)**

Finally, you can use some function like mv or MovFile depending on your Operating system with JNI.

I think it is out of scope of this topic. you can google it or see JNA library to accomplish your task if you want.

Here are complete code for you.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class MovefileTest {

    public static void moveWithApacheCommonsIO()
    {
        File sourceFile = new File("resource/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv");
        File destinationFile = new File("resource/aa/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv");

        try {
            FileUtils.moveFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void moveWithFileInOutStream()
    {
        File sourceFile = new File("resource/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv");
        File destinationFile = new File("resource/aa/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv");
        InputStream fin = null;
        OutputStream fout = null;

        sourceFile.deleteOnExit();

        try {
            fin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
            fout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationFile));

            byte[] readBytes = new byte[1024];
            int readed = 0;


            while((readed = fin.read(readBytes)) != -1)
            {
                fout.write(readBytes, 0, readed);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                fin.close();
                fout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public static void moveWithFileNIO()
    {
        File sourceFile = new File("resource/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv");
        File destinationFile = new File("resource/aa/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv");
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

        sourceFile.deleteOnExit();

        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final FileChannel inChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
        final FileChannel outChannel = outputStream.getChannel();

        try {
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                inChannel.close();
                outChannel.close();
                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //moveWithApacheCommonsIO();
        //moveWithFileNIO();
        moveWithFileInOutStream();

    }
}
```

Regards,

Comment: If you just want to move a file then Files.move is easy to use, it provides the ability the replace an existing file if you need it.

Comment: What if you don have Files.move? This is not a question. I did answer. why don you use it as an answer