# Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from HSSFWorkbook to Workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I use `poi-3.2-FINAL-20081019.jar` . Error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from HSSFWorkbook to Workbook

```
try {
            if (strType.equals("xls")) {
                wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            } else {
                wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            }
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use newer version:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.5-FINAL

Read more at: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html

Comment: Since `apache poi` is highly in development until now, it is always a good choice to use the latest stable version. This is version 3.17 now, see https://poi.apache.org/download.html. You may be confused from the confusing version numbering of `apache poi`. The version 3.5 is lower than 3.17 and should rather be 3.05.

Answer (score 1):

As the date in your jar shows - `poi-3.2-FINAL-20081019.jar` - you're usigng a jar that's almost 10 years old! You need to upgrade to something more modern, and at the very least something from this decade...

Right now (November 2017), the latest version is Apache POI 3.17. You can find the latest version on the [Apache POI homepage](http://poi.apache.org/), and see all the fixes in the [Changelog](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html)

In addition, you should swap to using [WorkbookFactory](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html) rather than looking at file extensions to work out what class to use. That hides all the detection complexity for you, works around mis-named files etc

Your code can then become the very simple

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("input.xlsx"));
Sheet s = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

(Use a `File` if you can, rather than `InputStream`, for lower memory)

Comment: "Use a File if you can, rather than InputStream" Hm, I would strongly suggest to **not** doing this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146161/apache-poi-fileinputstream-works-file-object-fails-nullpointerexception/46149469#46149469