# Apache POI appending data to xlsx file when task ran twice

Tags: apache-poi

I have a `template.xls` file that I'm adding data to from some database queries. I add the data and generate a new file named `yyyyMMddHHmmss.xls`. This works great. The file size is getting large so I'm trying to do the same with an `xlsx` file. When I generate the file the first time it works great. If I run the process again (even if I restart my java app) it's somehow retaining the last file in memory and appending the data to that file. In both cases it's pulling the source file from `template.xls(x)` which is an unmodified file.

The code between the two is identical except I'm passing in `xlsx` instead of `xls` in the latter case.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(classLoader.getResource("template.xlsx")).getFile());
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
// write data
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
String currentDate = formatter.format(date);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(currentDate + ".xlsx");
workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
fileOutputStream.close();
workbook.close();
```

I'm using `Java 8u201` and `org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.0` (also tried `4.0.1`)

Comment: Try whether using `Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file));` instead of using the `File` directly solves this issue. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146161/apache-poi-fileinputstream-works-file-object-fails-nullpointerexception/46149469#46149469 about the disadvantages with using a `File` for creating a `XSSFWorkbook`.

Comment: @AxelRichter if you want to promote that to answer that was the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As told in [Apache POI - FileInputStream works, File object fails (NullPointerException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146161/apache-poi-fileinputstream-works-file-object-fails-nullpointerexception/46149469#46149469) already, creating a `XSSFWorkbook` from a `File` has the disadvantage, that all changes which was made in that workbook always will be stored into that file while `XSSFWorkbook.write`. This is true even if  `write` writes to another file. But writing explicitly to the same file is not even possible because the `File` stays open after the workbook was created and so writing into that same file leads to exceptions.

So creating a `XSSFWorkbook` from a `File` using

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
```

is not a good idea when `file` is a `*.xlsx` file. Instead the `Workbook` needs to be created using a  `FileInputstream`:

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file));
```

Although the linked SO Q/A is from 2017, the same problem always nor occurs today using `apache poi 4.1.0`.