# SXSSFWorkbook write xlsm file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I copy `XSSFWorkbook` to `SXSSFWorkbook`. In this process, I create the new workbooks I use like this:

```
XSSFWorkbook readOnlyWb = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(f, null, true);
SXSSFWorkbook writeOnlyWb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
```

When writing to disk, the content type of the `SXSSFWorkbook` is always

```
/xl/workbook.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml
```

This is no issue, if the source workbook is an `.xlsx` file which has the same content type.

But I also have `.xlsm` files which I want to copy and they should remain to be `.xlsm` files. These files have the content type

```
/xl/workbook.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.main+xml
```

So basically the issue I have is, to dynamically get the right content type for each file type while using `SXSSFWorkbook`.

**How can I change the content type for the `SXSSFWorkbook` dynamically?**

Comment: You cannot create a `SXSSFWorkbook` having content type of `*.xlsm` from scratch, as well as you cannot create a `XSSFWorkbook` having content type of `*.xlsm` from scratch. Why not using the `*.xlsm` as template `workbook` in [new SXSSFWorkbook(workbook)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html#SXSSFWorkbook-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook-). That would work.

Comment: The issue with that is that I need to alter initial rows of the template, which is not allowed/possible to do with `SXSSFWorkbook`. From docs: `What is not supported:
Access initial cells and rows in the template.` as well as `Override existing cells and rows.`

Comment: That's true. That's why I asked. But there is not any method for creating `*.xlsm` from scratch in `apache poi`. The content type one could change using ugly low level manipulating the `[Content_Types].xml`. But what about the `vbaProject.bin` and it's relations? Would be very laborious.

Comment: Why not alter the initial rows of the template using `XSSFWorkbook` at first and then creating the `SXSSFWorkbook` from that changed `XSSFWorkbook` then for streaming in the rest of the data?

Comment: I am not allowed to perform any changes on the original files (that's why I open them in read-only mode). I am actually checking if the macros even need to be retained, which would solve the issue at hand if not. And as its not possible to copy macros, there is no sense in creating an empty `*.xlsm` template. Of course I could copy around the files a few times so to not alter the initial files, but I would like it to be as performant as possible

Comment: The `XSSFWorkbook` from which the `SXSSFWorkbook` is created is an object in memory. There is no need to change the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a `SXSSFWorkbook` having content type of `*.xlsm` from scratch, as well as you cannot create a `XSSFWorkbook` having content type of `*.xlsm` from scratch. But you can create a `XSSFWorkbook` form a `*.xlsm` file and this will preserve all the contents inclusive the content types and the `vbaProject.bin` `VBA` macro project as well. Then you can create the `SXSSFWorkbook` from that template `XSSFWorkbook` using constructor [SXSSFWorkbook(XSSFWorkbook workbook)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html#SXSSFWorkbook-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook-). After that the `SXSSFWorkbook` also will preserve all the contents.

If the need is changing some parts of the template `XSSFWorkbook`, then this must be done before the `SXSSFWorkbook` was created from that template. The `SXSSFWorkbook` is not able changing rows which already was in the template. This could be done in memory whithout changing the template file when the `XSSFWorkbook` is fully contained im memory. That is the case if it was created using a `InputStream`.

Following code shows that. It creates a `XSSFWorkbook`from a `*.xlsm` file using `FileInputStream`. Then it changes some parts of the template before it creates a `SXSSFWorkbook` from it. Then the big amout of date is streamed in in the `SXSSFWorkbook`. The result is a `*.xlsm` file having the correct content type and also having the  `vbaProject.bin` `VBA` macro project form the template as well.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.*;

public class CreateExcelSXSSFFromXLSM {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XSSFWorkbook templateWorkbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Workbook.xlsm"));
  Sheet sheet = templateWorkbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    System.out.println(cell);
    if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 0) cell.setCellValue("changed in template");
   }
  }

  int lastRowInTemplate = sheet.getLastRowNum();

  SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(templateWorkbook); 
  SXSSFSheet sxssfSheet = sxssfWorkbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
  for (int r = lastRowInTemplate + 1; r < lastRowInTemplate + 10; r++) {
   SXSSFRow row = sxssfSheet.createRow(r);
   for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
    SXSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);
    cell.setCellValue("R" + (r+1) + "C" + (c+1));
   }
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WorkbookNew.xlsm");
  sxssfWorkbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  sxssfWorkbook.close();
  sxssfWorkbook.dispose();
 }
}
```

Comment: Seems there is a difference between using a `File` object and an `FileInputStream` to load an `XSSFWorkbook` I didn't know about. This being the `Last Modified` date is updated when using a `File`, but not when using a `FileInputStream` (that was the reason I use `WorkbookFactory.create(f, null, true)`). Thanks for pointing that one out! Its a great answer and if I need to retain macros, this will definitly be my base

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: "Seems there is a difference between using a File object and an FileInputStream": Yes there is, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929312/apache-poi-appending-data-to-xlsx-file-when-task-ran-twice/55937539#55937539 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146161/apache-poi-fileinputstream-works-file-object-fails-nullpointerexception/46149469#46149469